# Should overloaded methods with value types be consolidated into a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, oop

When performing OO design, is it better to consolidate a collection of methods that use simple value types into a generic method ?  For example:

```
public int Sum(int x, int y)

// Overload with float.
public float Sum(float x, float y)
```

Consolidated to:

```
public T Sum<T> (T x, T y)
```

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general yes, however, specifically with your example (summing two arguments) - you can't do it with generics, since the `+` operator is not part of any interface to which you can constrain your generic type argument :)

(Note: this is my C# part talking, in other languages that might still be possible)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Is it not possible to do this or is it a bad design decision ?  I am thinking with the way it's written now that both parameters are unconstrained, so someone could pass any object in and the + operation is not overloaded for all types so it would break.  Does this sound right ?

Comment: Yes, a missing piece to the CLR - is an interface `INumeric` that would include those operators, (Applied to all the core types that implement them - int, uint, float, decimal, etc.)

Comment: @Scott Davies - No, it would not be possible (read - compile error), the compiler doesn't know how to translate the call to '+' for an unconstrained type. If the type is unconstrained, this is the case for any method, not just '+'.

Comment: No, it would not work as is, because as soon as you use the + operator inside this generic function, the compiler will complain because since you have not constrained the T type, it knows that not every type can use the + operator...

Comment: Ah, ok.  A compile time fault is good, then, as it stops this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In **some** cases, yes (not always); and despite rumour to the contrary, it is possible. I wrote some code for ["MiscUtil"](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) (free, etc) that does **exactly** this, and which works for all types with suitable operators (even your own structs and classes, or `Nullable<T>`, etc).

The problem here is that there is no interface that supports `Add` etc, so until `dynamic` comes along (in 4.0) it is tricky to do; but it can be done - here's the [usage page](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html), with a simiplfied `Sum` (the actual code in "MiscUtil" is slightly more complex):

```
public static T Sum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    T sum = Operator<T>.Zero;
    foreach (T value in source)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            sum = Operator.Add(sum, value);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Again, a lot of this is *relatively* simple in 4.0 with `dynamic`, since this supports operators; however, last time I benchmarked it, `dynamic` was slower than my (ab)use of `Expression`.

As an aside, the reason that standard LINQ *can* provide a `Min` / `Max` is because of `IComparable`/`IComparable<T>`, assisted by `Comparer<T>.Default`.