# Is there a way to write an Extension Method that applies to multiple types?

Tags: c#, .net, types, extension-methods

I'm trying to write an extension method that will add the function `HasFactor` to the class `int` in C#.  This works wonderfully, like so:

```
static class ExtendInt
{
    public static bool HasFactor(this int source, int factor)
    {
        return (source % factor == 0);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int i = 50;
        int f = 2;
        bool b = i.HasFactor(f);
        Console.WriteLine("Is {0} a factor of {1}? {2}",f,i,b);
        Console.ReadLine();
     }
}
```

This works great because variable `i` in the `Main()` method above is declared as an `int`.  However, if `i` is declared as an `Int16` or an `Int64`, the extension method does not show up unless it is explicitly cast as an `int` or `Int32`.

I now would like to apply the same `HasFactor` method to `Int16` and `Int64`.  However, I'd rather not write separate extension methods for each type of `int`.  I *could* write a single method for `Int64` and then explicitly cast everything as an `Int64` or `long` in order for the extension method to appear.

Ideally, I'd prefer to have the same extension method apply to all three types without having to copy and paste a lot of code.

**Is this even possible in C#?**  If not, is there a recommended best-practice for this type of situation?

Comment: Based on the input of Eilon and Marc Gravell, I think I'm going to create one extension method for type `Int64`.  This should work for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible in C#. You'll have to create one extension method for each type. The closest is to have an extension method that operates on an interface, but in this case there is no INumeric interface or anything similar that is implemented by the various numeric types.

Comment: Actually it is possible by some convoluted usage of Expression Trees (and/or dynamics if you're in .NET 4.0) - Check out Marc Gravel's answer to another SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987136/should-overloaded-methods-with-value-types-be-consolidated-into-a-generic-method/1987308#1987308, and his MiscUtil library.

Comment: Well, the **operators** (`%` etc) can use this - but not the extension method code. So I think (+1) that Eilon has the truth of it. A number of very similar overloads are in the future, I suspect.

Comment: That's interesting.  I'd be interested to know if `dynamic` (or some other .NET 4.0 feature) could be used to limit an extension method to specific types. Has this been done? (Perhaps this should be a separate SO question).

Comment: That's definitely an interesting idea. Though, I think even with dynamic, you'd want the type to implement IDynamicObject, which is of course not an option here since you don't own the types in question (int, long, etc.).